# LZString decompression in swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

[image]I am having a web service which gives LZCompressed string in my iOS app. To decompress the LZ string I have tried the following solutions.

1. https://github.com/takagi-denki/lzstring-swift
2. https://github.com/TapMesh/LZCompression

Both are working for me when I am decompressing small strings. But when I am getting LZStrings with larger size both of these are not working. (The crash I faced is added in the github issues section. Also I have added the crash details in the screenshot)

Any better suggestion for LZString conversion from iOS project? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. Have you found any solutions to this problem?

Comment: @NikitaShpakau I found a solutions. I will add as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes in the code takagi-denki have published in GitHub and fixed the issue. The bug free code can access from here https://github.com/mohammedabdulbasithk/lz-string-swift

Answer (score 0):

I have added submitted a PR to fix this issue for now.
For the time being while the PR is not approved, you can use a forked copy of the Package here.

[SPM Package](https://github.com/Ibrahimhass/lzstring-swift)